# Timestamp from Node is 3 minutes behind when converted to Python datetime

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime, python-3.x

I have a Node/Express API that sets a timestamp on a Mongoose model:

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    created_on: {
        type: Number,
        default: new Date().getTime()
    },
    . . .
});
```

When I convert this into a Python datetime in Django:

```
created_on = datetime.fromtimestamp(notification['created_on'] / 1000.0)
```

it's exactly 3 minutes behind. Both applications are running on the same server. What's going on with this timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out. It was as simple as specifying the default value as:

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    created_on: {
        type: Number,
        default: Date.now
    },
    . . .
});
```

Now each time a model gets saved, Date.now is called properly.